# Setting React state array in onChange event only captures the first character

Tags: arrays, onchange, react-state

I'm trying to update an array of objects in state using a single change handler. As soon as I type in the input it captures the first character, loses focus on the input box, and doesn't show the value I typed in the input. The single value will show in the console log though and it is in the correct place for the array object.

Here's my handler:

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const tempDrops: RiserDrop[] = [...dropsBefore];
    const id = parseInt(e.target.id.split("-")[1]);
    const index = id - startingPot1;
    const property = e.target.id.split("-")[0];

    if (property === "te") {
      tempDrops[index].te = parseInt(e.target.value);
    } else if (property === "de") {
      tempDrops[index].de = parseInt(e.target.value);
    } else if (property === "age") {
      tempDrops[index].age = parseInt(e.target.value);
    }

    console.log(tempDrops);
    //setDropsBefore(tempDrops);
  };
```

When I comment out the setDropsBefore line the console log shows the array being properly updated no matter how many I update. It's always correct and flowing fine, but as soon as I uncomment that line the new array just won't make it to the state. Is there a better way to update my state array or am I doing something wrong?